# How can I fix the formatting for this print? Preferably using pandas if possible

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

I've been looking at trying to print the results of this query using results[0][0] which is a userID in my database.

```
test = "SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE UserID = ?"
test1 = c.execute(test, (results[0][0],))
test2 = c.fetchall()
print(test2)
```

As this is, the results do print but not in a format that is readable to the user:

```
[(13, 1), (14, 1), (15, 1), (16, 1)]
```

I've tried a few different methods of converting this to a pandas print but haven't had any success, so some pointers on this would be very much appreciated, thanks.

UPDATE:

Looking to format like this:

```
OrderID       UserID

 Data          Data
```

I've tried using the pandas `read_sql_query`

One of the methods I've tried so far using the `read_sql_query`

```
def test():
    print(pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM Products WHERE UserID = ?", conn), (results[0][0],))
test()
```

New code using a dataframe:

```
test = "SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE UserID = ?"
test1 = c.execute(test, (results[0][0],))
test2 = c.fetchall()
df = pd.DataFrame(data=test2)
df.rename(columns={'0': 'OrderID', '1': 'UserID'})
print(df)
```

I have attempted to rename the columns, however when running the program it still names the columns `0` and `1` rather than the expected results.

Current print:

```
    0  1
0  13  1
1  14  1
2  15  1
3  16  1
```

Comment: You should show us your desired `print` output.

Comment: my desired output would be something along the lines of how it appears here: https://imgur.com/a/dEHHG9g

Comment: You should add that to your original question, best in a format of not a screenshot. Also there is `pandas` function `read_sql` and `read_sql_query`, check that out.

Comment: ill update the post now, ive tried read sql before and i either end up with nothing printed or an error, I'll add some of the ones of tried already if you know the proper format that could help it work?

Comment: In your comments you want to `print` but in the screenshot you present a table = `data frame` which makes more sense. Try using `read_sql_query` which returns `data frame`

Comment: dataframe has worked to reformat that, just need to rename the columns now. I found df.rename but it seems to have no effect. I'll update post again

Answer (score 0):

```
test = "SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE UserID = ?"
test1 = c.execute(test, (results[0][0],))
test2 = c.fetchall()
df = pd.DataFrame(data=test2)
df.columns = ['OrderID', 'UserID']
print(df)
```

Complete solution with ability to rename columns and using dataframe instead of read_sql

print:

```
  OrderID  UserID
0       13       1
1       14       1
2       15       1
3       16       1
```